# SQLAlchemy modelling a constraint based on a dictionary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i have a table like this:

```
class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sample'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Enum(u'Lion', u'Tiger', name='types'))
    color = Column(Enum(... a specific list based on type ...))
```

and an dictionary:

```
colors = { 'Lion' : ['gold', 'orange'],
           'Tiger' : ['blackorange', 'whiteblue']
         }
```

now i want a Constraint which allows that the color attribute in my Sample can only be a item in the correspondent list.

Which is the clever way to to this?

(only way i found with a sort of setter method: [Using Descriptors and Hybrids](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#using-descriptors-and-hybrids))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event listeners:

```
colors = { 'Lion' : ['gold', 'orange'],
           'Tiger' : ['blackorange', 'whiteblue']
         }
class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sample'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Enum(u'Lion', u'Tiger', name='type'))
    color = Column(Enum('gold', 'orange', 'blackorange', 'whiteblue', name='color'))

from sqlalchemy import event

def my_check_sample_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    assert target.color in colors[target.type]

event.listen(Sample, 'before_insert', my_check_sample_listener)
event.listen(Sample, 'before_update', my_check_sample_listener)

sample = Sample(type='Tiger', color='orange')
session.add(sample)
session.commit() # Fails

sample = Sample(type='Lion', color='orange')
session.add(sample)
session.commit() # OK

sample.type = 'Tiger'
sample.color = 'whiteblue'
session.commit() # OK

sample.color = 'orange'
session.commit() # Fails
```

Comment: After reading through the [event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html) chapter i see so much room for improvement, thanks!